# debug gdb-debuggable fortran executable in xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, gfortran

i have created a debuggable fortran executable (let's call it 'myfortranprogram') and I am able to debug, set breakpoints, etc. by passing it through the gdb debugger:

```
cd sourcedir/
gdb myfortranprogram
#start debugging
```

Suppose the source files are in the same source directory 'sourcedir', if that makes a difference at all.

So compiling with the terminal becomes a little bit slow for very large projects and I would prefer to debug using the XCode interface. Since myfortranprogram is already a debuggable executable, what are the steps i have to take to get it debugged in XCode? It is my understanding that XCode is able to debug using gdb.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the answer:
http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-807021.html

it's simple, just create an empty project in xcode, point a new custom executable to the path of the compiled application, and do 'run myexecutablename'